# When to use "!=" and "is not"

Tags: ansible, conditional-statements, ansible-2.x

Ansible: 2.9

When should you use `!=` or `is not` in `when` before `include: create_dir.yml` in Ansible?

Example code:

```yaml
- name: "Get stat"  
   stat:
     path: "/tmp"
   register: stat_result

- include: create_dir.yml
  when: stat_result.exists is not True
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of, you do have two issues in the tasks you are producing here:

1. you want to use the module `file` or the module `stat` but not a strange mixture of both
2. the `stat` module would give you a complex type `stat` containing the key `exists`, so really you should test `stat_result.stat.exists`

So, the explanation below is based on the tasks:

```yaml
- stat:
    path: "/tmp"
  register: stat_result

- include: create_dir.yml
  when: stat_result.stat.exists is not true
```

Which **is** a working couple of tasks.

---

As pointed in Jinja's documentation:

> **is**: Performs a [test](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#tests).

<sup>*Source https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#other-operators*</sup>

> **!=**: Compares two objects for inequality.

<sup>*Source https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#comparisons*</sup>

But since there are a [`true()`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#true) and [`false()`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#false) tests defined in Jinja, you could indeed write something like:

```yaml
when: stat_result.stat.exists is not true()
```

And so a shorter version would be

```yaml
when: stat_result.stat.exists is not true 
# because the test function receives no parameters
```

Now indeed this test is similar to

```yaml
when: stat_result.stat.exists != True
```

At the exception that the `is not true` test is more robust and would cope with undefined variables better than `!= True`

For example, if you do comment your `stat` task, the test

```yaml
when: stat_result.stat.exists is not true
```

would succeed, while

```yaml
when: stat_result.stat.exists != True
```

would raise a fatal error:

> The conditional check 'stat_result.stat.exists != True' failed. The error was: error while evaluating conditional (stat_result.stat.exists != True): 'stat_result' is undefined

---

Now this test is really not optimal, because you should not do things like `when: bool_var is not true` you should rater do `when: not bool_var`, so:

```yaml
when: not stat_result.stat.exists
```

Comment: Hi! I correct the example code. Thank's a lot for this tutorial.